# Weird ProFTPd and mod_sql string escaping

Tags: sql, proftpd

I am using/trying to use ProFTPd with users in SQL and using stock sql configuration.

I currently have a problem with weird string escaping, but ONLY for INSERT into the "tally" table, not for SELECT.

My conf is

```
SQLNamedQuery get-quota-tally SELECT "name,quota_type,bytes_in_used,bytes_out_used,bytes_xfer_used,files_in_used,files_out_used,files_xfer_used FROM ftp_quota_tally WHERE name = '%{0}' AND quota_type = '%{1}'"

SQLNamedQuery insert-quota-tally FREEFORM "INSERT INTO ftp_quota_tally (name,quota_type,bytes_in_used,bytes_out_used,bytes_xfer_used,files_in_used,files_out_used,files_xfer_used) VALUES (%{0}, %{1}, %{2}, %{3}, %{4}, %{5}, %{6}, %{7})"
```

The sql query log shows this for the SELECT:

```
2020-09-15 03:53:37,317 mod_sql/4.5[19831]: query "SELECT name,quota_type,bytes_in_used,bytes_out_used,bytes_xfer_used,files_in_used,files_out_used,files_xfer_used FROM ftp_quota_tally WHERE name = 'USERNAME_HERE' AND quota_type = 'user'"
```

which is ok, but it shows

```
2020-09-15 03:53:37,321 mod_sql/4.5[19831]: query "INSERT INTO ftp_quota_tally (name,quota_type,bytes_in_used,bytes_out_used,bytes_xfer_used,files_in_used,files_out_used,files_xfer_used) VALUES (\'USERNAME_HERE\', \'user\', 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0, 0, 0)"
```

ProFTPd escapes the ${0} and ${1} with `\'`.

NOTE:

(1) I already tried to use this sql query

```
SQLNamedQuery insert-quota-tally FREEFORM "INSERT INTO ftp_quota_tally (name,quota_type,bytes_in_used,bytes_out_used,bytes_xfer_used,files_in_used,files_out_used,files_xfer_used) VALUES ('%{0}', '%{1}', %{2}, %{3}, %{4}, %{5}, %{6}, %{7})"
```

which leads to more escaping

```
2020-09-15 04:15:58,490 mod_sql/4.5[20643]: query "INSERT INTO ftp_quota_tally (name,quota_type,bytes_in_used,bytes_out_used,bytes_xfer_used,files_in_used,files_out_used,files_xfer_used) VALUES ('\'USERNAME_HERE\'', '\'user\'', 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0, 0, 0)"
```

(2) I also tried the non-FREEFORM way

```
INSERT "%{0}, %{1}, %{2}, %{3}, %{4}, %{5}, %{6}, %{7}" ftp_quota_tally
```

which leads also to the same weird escaping as in my FREEFORM-way.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which ProFTPD, and which database backend module, are you using?  The string-escaping routines tend to be database-specific.

Comment: I am using MySQL as database engine, compiled against mysql-connector-c 8.0.21

Comment: Can you help point me in the direction of downloading that mysql-connector-c 8.0.21 library?  Most Linux packages use "libmysqlclient-dev" or similar.  There's a mysql-connector-c++, but that's not the same.  I'd like to reproduce this issue locally.

Answer (score 0):

The cause for this issue was tracked down to be a bug in ProFTPD, starting with the 1.3.7 release; see [Issue #1149](https://github.com/proftpd/proftpd/issues/1149).